# What will be the performance difference between using SSH and SSL?

Tags: performance, ssl, ssh

Assume, I have two choices.

1. Use self-signed x.509 certificate on both the server and client and validate server using its certificate stored in client and authenticate client using client certificate stored in server.
2. Create only keys on both the server and client and validate server using server key stored in the client and authenticate client using client key stored in the server.

Assume we will use RSA with key length of 2048.

My query is what will be the performance difference. My worry is overhead involved in taking key out of certificate and doing channel encryption.

Our case is there will more number of requests and not much data to flow.

Let me know if you have any queries or concerns.

Comment: The overhead involved in getting a key out a certificate is negligible, and channel encryption has to occur in both SSL and SSH. SSH probably has a slight overhead for the channels facility but OTOH it may be faster in other ways. I'd be surprised if there was anything significant in it, but you should almost certainly use SSL to be like everything else you will have deployed. NB OpenSSL is an API, not a communications technology.

Comment: SSL also provides session resumption. I'm not aware that SSH has such a feature.

Comment: Thanks EJP, for both(ssh and ssl) methods I am planning to use openssl.

Comment: yes we have reconnect feature. but I am not sure this will help in broken connections to resume. Need to study more on ssl session resumption.

Comment: Your question is about SSH versus SSH. How you implement both isn't relevant in the terms of your question. SSL session resumption shortens the SSL handshake, considerably. You should not be planning around broken connections: rather, you should be planning to avoid them; but broken connections don't affect the validity of an SSL session as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

`SSL` and `SSH` they are all have the same functionality, which is Encryption. Both are Cryptographic Network protocols.

**SSL:**

port: 443

Application : Encryption between browser and server

**SSH :**

port : 22

Application : Between two Computers

This is the picture of Version Control system which has got SSH key to communicate between user and their repository!

Know how to generate SSH key [Here!!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57778147/11235609)

Know how to Generate SSL key [Here!!](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-generate-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-on-linux/)

Credits :[Medium](https://medium.com/@tu7a1k23/the-difference-between-ssl-https-protocol-and-ssh-protocol-c06689180bac)