# How to Create SSH Key in git

Tags: git, ssh-keys

I using the following command to create SSH key in git

`$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`

on git bash, but when I enter this command on bash it is displaying another command list and not generate SSH Key. Then how can I generate Key?

Comment: Please provide the output you're getting.

Comment: it is some kind of other command manuals. difficult to copy all one is this `ssh-keygen -p`

Comment: Did you literally include `$` in your command? You should not, that `$` is a prompt that bash displays. The command you type should start with `ssh-keygen…`

Answer (score 3):

Create your ssh key using `ssh-keygen -o -t rsa -b 4096 -C "email@example.com"`

After list file in folder ~./ssh and see if your key exist. Use:

`ls ~/.ssh/`

Answer (score 1):

**To Generate ssh:**

**Step 1:**

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "example@gmail.com"
```

Replace it with Your Mail id

Enter passphrase if you want you can leave this blank

**Step 2:**

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
```

You will get Agent pid (Don't Need to copy it)

**Step 3:**

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

**Step 4:**

```
cat < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Copy Down the Displayed key including your mail id

Then **Goto Github > Settings > SSH And GPG keys > Click New RSA(Green Button) > Give a random title to the key and paste down the key below Tap Add SSH Key.**

Answer (score 0):

ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_github_email_address"

dont write any passphrase, so enter

```
Overwrite (y/n)? y
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): enter
Enter same passphrase again: enter

pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
cd ~/.ssh
cat id_ed25519.pub
```

and copy the content to github

```
ssh-..e9 AAA...+T5 abc@gmail.com
```

https://medium.com/codex/clone-github-private-repository-using-ssh-on-mac-acc9110d1cfe

Answer (score 0):

Using SSH (Secure Shell) instead of https seems the Secure & Fastest method.  Just providing few links and tips here to make things a bit easy.  You can check this [step-by-step guide](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh)! provided by docs.github to "Check existing SSH keys, Generate, Add a new SSH key to your GitHub account, and more."

Tip #1:  During the process you need to confirm SSH key fingerprints to validate the connection.  Compare the key of the algorithm you chose respectively (RSA, ECDSA, or Ed25519) and confirm it.  Check this link to compare the key:  [GitHub's public key fingerprints](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints)!

Tip #2:  If you don't want to type passphrase every time you push, just press enter when it prompts to choose passphrase.

**CAUTION:** Other methods using https $ git config credential.helper store etc., even with using 'timeout' might seem faster but are 100% unencrypted and hence not secure.  However, you can encrypt that config file and just decrypt it before use, but there is still a chance we might forget to encrypt it again after use.  You can use it at your discretion.